# multi_match fuzzy query across multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am working to match a 'term' to multi fields (or _all field)
I want to do a fuzzy match on cross_fields but it is not supported.
any ideas how to do it or any other ways to do it ?

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
    query: term,
    type: "cross_fields",
    fields: ['_all']
  }
}
```

when trying the solution here

[ElasticSearch multi_match query over multiple fields with Fuzziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632339/elasticsearch-multi-match-query-over-multiple-fields-with-fuzziness)

I get this error

> [parsing_exception] Fuziness not allowed for type [cross_fields], with
>   { line=1 & col=128 }

elasticsearch version 5.0

edit:
here is the query I am building

```
bool: {
       must: [
             {
             fuzzy: {
                     _all: term
                     }
             },
             {
             fuzzy: {
                    "location.country": country
                    }
             },
             {
             fuzzy: {
                    "location.city": city
                    }
             }
             ]
      }
```

Comment: A cross_field on one field is nonsense. a simple match on _all field is enough. And you will have the fuzziness available.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN, I tried _all: fullTerm and it is not working. fullTerm is term + country + city

Answer (score 1):

`cross_fields` works by searching the term on your multiple fields. Since fuzziness isn't supported for cross_fields you have to write the query in a different way.

One possible is: implement your own "cross_fields" with shoulds and add there the fuzziness.

Say your term is: "term1 term2", you can split by word boundary (Regex `\b`) then should them in this form:

```
{
   {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "field1": "term",
                        "fuzziness": 1
                    }
                },{
                    "match": {
                        "field1": "term",
                        "fuzziness": 1
                    }
                },{
                    "match": {
                        "field2": "term1",
                        "fuzziness": 1
                    }
                },{
                    "match": {
                        "field2": "term12",
                        "fuzziness": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is probably less the optimal if you have many fields, the query will become a cartesian product of the terms and fields.

*Important note* You're using _all field which is one field. which all other fields are indexed into. Maybe you don't even need cross_fields?

Comment: according to the doc , the should query will match even if only one in matching. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

> If the bool query is a filter context or has neither must or filter then at  least one of the should queries must match a document for it to match  the bool query.